# Learning a model which can fit the training data accurately

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am using weka for creating a model on a training set for a classification task. I am trying different classifiers for this. But when I try to give one of the data points which are present in the training set, it misclassifies it. Partly the reason might be that when we are creating a model, we are trying to learn a mixture of distributions in order to classify a future data point. Is there a way to accurately fit the training data ? I doubt that this might defeat the whole purpose of machine learning but I would like to know if there exists any ?

Comment: What is the error rate on training set and test set? You can fit your training set if the classifier's representation power is enough. However that doesn't mean a better classifier because of over-fitting problem. Check over-fitting and underfitting (bias/variance problem) if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: A decision tree with unlimited depth will give your a perfect training classification, it happens because the space hypothesis has infinity cardinality, it can **memorize** anything, but I don't get the point of this, you will not **learn**.

Answer (score 1):

Ability to perfectly fit the training set varies from model to model. It might not be possible to do it by fitting a mixture of distributions that you are using, but it should be possible to do it by fitting, say, a very deep decision tree.

And you should not have any doubts: forcefully [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) in this manner will most definitely defeat the whole purpose of machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to have is a perfect classification on your training set = zero bias. This can be achieved with complex models = high variance.

If you have a look at the figure below, you can easily see that a linear model could never classify all the samples perfectly even if the model learn from all the samples. A fully grown decision tree will however be able to classify all your samples if it has learn from all the data.

[image: LDA classification]